# Profile JUnit in Eclipse Indigo using VisualVM

Tags: java, junit, profiling, profiler, visualvm

How can I profile a JUnit Test, preferentially with Eclipse integrated support? I'm trying to do it using VisualVM but apparently it can't be done.

I'm using Windows 7 x64, Eclipse Indigo, jdk 1.6, jre-j9 and JUnit 3 (I could use v.4)

Comment: What is your problem when using VisualVM? I have used it before, and it worked.

Comment: @Axel I can use it to launch java programs (with main method) but when I try to profile a JUnit (selecting VisualVM as the launcher instead of Eclipse JUnit Launcher) I get a NullPointerException error message box and the test is runned on Eclipse.

Comment: @Axel how did you do this?

Comment: Err... I start VisualVM and connect to the process.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use JVisualVM (`%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jvisualvm.exe`), but to use it with JUnit, you need to change the run configuration slightly.

1. Run the JUnit tests once, to create the run configuration
2. Edit the Run Configuration (`Run->Run Configurations...`)
3. In the `Test` tab check the box 'Keep JUnit running after test when debugging'
4. Rerun the test (with Debug). This will run the tests, but importantly, leave the JVM around, so that you can attach to it using JVisualVM.

If you wish to profile a specific section of the test, then setting a breakpoint before and after will enable you to start / stop profiling.

Comment: It take forever for me to run a Spring JUnit test with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner. Checking this option obviates all that. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I find re-running the tests starts a different VM (not the one being monitored), so no data is collected. As a workaround I put a breakpoint in the constructor/@Parameters initialization, then I can link monitor before test is run.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Ok, the solution kind of works ... You open jvisualvm and then "Sample" the  RemoteTestRunner, and you can get some meaningufl feedback out of the experience. But compared to the Nebeans profile Junit test, this approach just does not compete. Depending on the omplexity of the unit test,  the volumes of data you make to stress it, unless a decent plugin is found for this, I would just get vanilla netbeans, and have it do the analysis. If it is not worth the time investment, than the visualvm sampling approach is ok.

Comment: @Stefan: Seems your link is broken - I get a "Page not found". Anyway I don't get a Nullpointer with Neon Release (4.6.0).

Comment: @ timguy. Thanks. My nullpointer exception has been due to a missing path to the visualvm executable in the settings of the VisualVm Launcher and not due to Neon (as I assumed first).

Comment: @Javier: the first run is not for profiling, but just to create a run configuration for steps 2 and 3.

Answer (score 7):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) has an eclipse plugin which supports JUnit run configurations. See [here](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/06/jprofilers-ide-integrations.html) for a screen cast on the eclipse IDE integration.

To keep the JVM alive after the test finishes (so that you can analyzed the results), edit the profiling settings and select "Keep VM alive" on the "Miscellaneous" tab.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Comment: Is there a test period, or do you have to buy it upfront?

Comment: There is a 10 day evaluation period when you download it, but can get more time as well.

Answer (score 2):

A neat option to profile application startup or short running processes (like tests) with VisualVM is the [Startup Profiler Plugin](https://visualvm.github.io/startupprofiler.html).

The command line argument provided by the plugin has to be copied to the launch configuration under VM arguments.

Comment: Super handy tip! Thanks for sharing. Was thinking it'd be nice if the plugin could also trigger the sampling-profiler (much faster) but the instrumenting profiler will do. And actually, I suppose I should be focusing on call-counts anyway since timings are soooooo skewed by "cold run bias" (things like class-loading often dominate, vs the actual code itself).